# BeautifulSoup web scraping multiple pages URL doesn't change

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination, request

When using beautiful soup to webscrape reviews I have an issue when it comes to "All Audience" Reviews. The URL doesn't update when changing review list pages.

Here is an example:
https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/midsommar/reviews?type=user

No change in the URL is made when clicking next.

Based on some of the other answers available in another thread I tried (and I might be saying this wrong) tracking xhr request, I believe the exact script that is being run is what I have highlighted in the picture here(I don't have 10 reputation so can't post image).

[Network Method Post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh8Yu.jpg)

When I look into the header of that GET action I see a Request URL, and when I try that it has all of the info I need, the problem is I don't know their naming convention for going to the next page. Below is how the RequestURLs change between pages.

[Request URL page 1->2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewspl.jpg)

[Request URL page 2->3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZRFM.jpg)

How can I get beautiful soup to iterate over these?

Thanks!

Below should be enough code to get by attempting this, ignore some of the naming.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

x = input('What Movie?').replace(" ", "_").lower()

req_rot = Request('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/' + str(x) + '/reviews?type=user', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

webpage_rot = urlopen(req_rot).read()

page_soup_rot = soup(webpage_rot, "html.parser")

reviews_rot = page_soup_rot.findAll("div",{"class":"audience-reviews__review-wrap"})

z_rot = re.findall(r'js-clamp"(.+)</p>', str(reviews_rot))

Movie_Adj_rot = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  str(z_rot)).split()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better description for this issue is windowed pagination, the simplest solution I found was to just learn selenium and insert a scrape function within a ranged loop of clicking the next button element on each page.